# Recognize a click on item in notification bar

Tags: android

I need to hide a overlay on the screen when user clicks on a notification bar item, so he'll can smoothly go out of my app, Is there any way to get the relevant intent/vent when use interacts with the notification bar?

P.S the notification is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, this will be a major security issue if possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve this via `PendingIntent` and register your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

So you can perform actions in the new `Activity`

Answer (score -1):

Make your Activity sigle task by providing `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

After that give your `Activity` as a `PendingIntent` to your notification with some special data in it.

When your activity is not there at all, you will get `onCreate()` method. You can populate your screen normally.

If your activity is already in foreground, you will get `onNewIntent()` function. Overwrite `onNewIntent()` function and check whether the data which you have put in notification is there. If it is there, you can update your UI and hide your overlay.